# How to use install Ioncube Loader and use it in terminal mac

Tags: ioncube

I tried installing ioncube but I am unable to do it in my mac. Please help me with the solution. I want to run php script in terminal which is encoded by ioncube

Comment: please provide more information. what exactly did you do, what were the error messages, etc.

Comment: In principle installation is simple, and just requires the relevant Loader .so file to be installed and referenced in the primary php.ini file with a `zend_extension` line. The Loader Wizard from https://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php is a PHP script that can guide you and indicate the correct Loader based on the operating system type and whether the PHP build is 32 or 64 bit.